# How to attach file upload with state values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my React State

```
this.state = {
            data : {
                employee_Name:"" ,
                employee_Id:"",
                employee_Doj:"",
                employee_ResumeFile:""
             }
}
```

I am getting uploaded file data on change

```
onChangeHandler=event=>{
    const data = { ...this.state.data }; 
    data.employee_ResumeFile = event.target.files[0];
    this.setState({ data }); 
    console.log(data);

}
```

How to add this to my axios along with existing state data

```
doSubmit() {    
   // How to add this form data inside my axios
    const data = new FormData() 
    data.append('file', this.state.data.employee_ResumeFile)

   axios.put(apiEndpoint+'/update/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/basic-details',{
        employee_Name:this.state.data.employee_Name, 
        employee_Id: this.state.data.employee_Id,
        employee_Doj:this.state.data.employee_Doj, 
        employee_ResumeFile.state.data.employee_ResumeFile
      })
}
```

Should we use only formdata() to send file if then how to add formdata value inside my axios with existing values

Comment: Hi, Yes to upload any file to the server you must send the body in the formData()

Comment: @rashijain how to add 
        const data = new FormData() 
        data.append('file', this.state.data.employee_ResumeFile) this inside my axios with with existing values

Comment: you need to append the complete body into formData
 ```let formData = new FormData();
 formData.append('file', this.state.data.employee_ResumeFile);
 formData.append(employee_Name,this.state.data.employee_Name);
...


```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes use `FormData` and make sure to add correct headers.

**Like this**

```js
doSubmit() {   
     const data = new FormData() 
     data.append('file', this.state.data.employee_ResumeFile)
     data.append('name', this.state.data.employee_Name)
     data.append('id', this.state.data.employee_Id)
     data.append('doj', this.state.data.employee_Doj)
     const config = {
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'multipart/form-data' // <-- Set header for 
        }
    }
    axios.put(apiEndpoint+'/update/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/basic-details',data, config)
 }
```

**Editing**  based on comments.
If lot of stuff needs to be appended to formdata, then you can maintain it in an object and loop thru it using `for in` and dynamically append stuff to formData.

As I see in your question that you have fields maintained in the state, so you can do something like this.

```js
    ...
    const data = new FormData() 
    for(let key in this.state.data) {
        data.append(key,this.state.data[key]);
    }
    ...
    // axios.post code....
```

Comment: any better way to write this  data.append('id', this.state.data.employee_Id) for more number of fileds I have 70 such field any better ways ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FormData` and `append` the file that you want to upload,

```
const data = new FormData() 
data.append('file', this.state.data.employee_ResumeFile)

axios.put(apiEndpoint+'/update/'+this.props.match.params.id+'/basic-details', data)
```

try to do REST API using `post` method except `put`.

Comment: I need to append some more field values along with it formData.append(employee_Name,this.state.data.employee_Name);

Comment: Why not to use PUT

Comment: Ok, you can append all the fields as you like. 
```
data.append('file', this.state.data.employee_ResumeFile)
data.append('employee_Name',this.state.data.employee_Name)
data.append(.........)
```

Comment: PUT is meant as a method for "uploading" stuff to a particular URI or overwriting what is already in that URI. POST, on the other hand, is a way of submitting data RELATED to a given URI. 
Here you are uploading files with other data. Therefore I think the POST method is better than PUT.